# How to perform :DiffOrig against the commted file

Tags: vim, git

VIM has a terrific [:DiffOrig](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#%3aDiffOrig) command to diff the file in the buffer with the file on the disk. How might one diff against the file in Git (as would be returned with a `git checkout` command) instead of diffing against the file on disk?

Answer (score 2):

The [fugitive.vim - A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) plugin integrates Git with Vim. Among others, it defines a `:Gdiff` command, which performs a vimdiff against the index; use `:Gdiff HEAD` for against the committed version.